# How to convert a list item to int/double

Tags: java, string, list

I Made a list:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

String someData = "1234";

list.add(someData);
```

Is there any way to convert `someData` to `int` or `double`? The reason why i made it a `String` in the first place is that I had to input few informations (using loop) from a `Scanner`. Most of them is a `String`. And now I will need few of them to be int-like 'cause I want to do some math operations.

Comment: You can also ask just use `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` from your `Scanner`.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(someData);
```

I don't really see what the List has to do with it? If you want a List of Integers, you could use:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

String someData = "1234"; 
list.add(Integer.parseInt(someData));
```

Same goes for: `List<Double>` and `Double.parseDouble()`.

Note that `parseInt()` can throw a `NumberFormatException`. Either make sure that this will not be the case, or handle it with a try-catch.

Comment: Worth noting that `parseInt` can throw a `NumberFormatException` which you can catch and handle to your convenience. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: And while we're at it, there's also `Double.parseDouble()`, and DSquare's note also applies here too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as suggested by other answers or change how you scan data at the origin:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (shouldScan) {
  int value = scanner.nextInt();
  list.add(value);
  ..
}
```

Mind that you should take care of catching a `InputMismatchException` exception in case the input format is wrong.

If you choose to use `Integer.parseInt(string)` you should take care of catching `NumberFormatException` instead.

Comment: Just in case OP *does* change how he uses the scanner, it might be good to point out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint just in case

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
int flag=Integer.valueOf(someData);
```

And if you want to store it in an Integer list you can simply use :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(Integer.valueOf(someData));
```